# Error: The getter 'auth' isn't defined for the class 'Object'

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

The code where I have used Provider. I keep getting this error **Error: The getter 'auth' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.**

```
 FutureBuilder(
                future: Provider.of<Object>(context).auth.getCurrentUID,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
                    {
                      print("done");
                    }
                  else{
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                  return Container();
                },
              ),
```

Please help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please share your provider class

Comment: You need to do the type casting. You need to write your current model instead of Provider.of<Object>

For example Provider.of<Auth>

Comment: I'm new to Flutter, can you tell me how to create the provider class?

Comment: What is a current model? do you mean the provider class name?